# Trigger async Event in blazor server side app

Tags: c#, events, async-await, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to raise an event within my service to check something within a blazor server app.

Lets consider this service for example:

```
public class TestService
{
    public static event AsyncEventHandler<EventArgs> OnTest;

    public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {

        // DO SOMETHING
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
        await Task.Delay(50);

        await OnTest.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public Task AsyncEventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e) where TEventArgs : EventArgs;
```

It has a method `DoSomethingAsync` which invokes my `AsyncEventHandler`.

When the page loads, it registers itself to the event like this:

```
protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    TestService.OnTest += TestService_OnTest;
    return base.OnInitializedAsync();
}

private async Task TestService_OnTest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new Exception();
}

public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    TestService.OnTest -= TestService_OnTest;

    return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
}
```

The `AsyncEventHandler` allows me to `await` `.Invoke` of my event. This results in the user who instanciated the event to crash as expected.

What I want to do is this:

- User1 is on Page a and selects some elements
- User2 is on the same page as User1 and selects some elements and he/she is pressing save before User1
- I want the page of User1 to revalidate his selects based on the selects that User2 did (so he can't select what User2 has already selected)
- If the code raises any exception, I don't want it to be fire and forget for either User2 and User1.

How can I achive this?

Comment: Define "crashed".   And I'm not sure I understand "it's implementation of the event".  Do you mean the handler it has registered?

Comment: The way I understand it, you'd like if one of the threads has a problem, the rest of the threads will automatically have a problem as well. If it is so, Why would you like to do that? When you define the methods async, each one is executed in its own thread, and you can manage the exception created for the intended thread by defining the `try catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your trying to achieve with your "AsyncEventHandler".

Events are "Fire and Forget".  The handler calls them and then carries on it's way as soon as they either complete or yield.  The handler doesn't await them if they yield.

That doesn't mean that any registered handler can't be async.

```cs
private async Void OnSomethingChanged(object? sender, EnventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Dalay(1000);
    //...
}
```

Is a perfectly valid handler.  It will execute but there's nothing waiting on it's completion.

You can try and raise exceptions in event handlers, but while the code is run in the context of the owner, the code is executed in the context of the event holder.  Exceptions bubble up in the execution context, not the parent context.

This doesn't stop you popping up windows in other user's sessions to say things have gone wrong, but actual system exceptions, no: I know of no way to raise them.

Comment: I've put a better explanation into my question to make it more clear what I'm trying to achive.